# Using angular router with Google's webcache

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

#### Summary

I'm trying to be able to display my Angular 2 project in Google's webcache. App components like header/footer display, but everything within router-outlet does not appear.

All modules loaded with the router are lazy loaded if that makes a difference.

#### Project Details

- Angular 4.0.1
- Webpack 2.2.1
- Java Backend (no Universal)

#### The Problem In Detail

My team's SEO person would like the content to show up in Google's webcache. The 'fetch as Google' tool works as it should and everything looks to be readable but apparently we need it to display cached as well.

Everything outside of the router-outlet gets displayed fine. I get a few similar CORS errors (which I'll post below) because obviously instead of the usual URL, the url when viewing cached page is webcache.googleuser.content.etc.

Now I know Universal became available with version 4 which may be able to help out here but we're using a Java Spring back end and by the looks of things, support for that is still in development.

I found a website built with Angular that has exactly the same issue as the one I'm having so to see it in action, put 'cache:' before the url in chrome's address bar. [Here is the site in question](https://code.gov).

So basically, has anyone had to deal with this issue yet and how did they solve it? Is it even possible without using Univeral?

#### The Error

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL '{USUAL URL}' cannot be created in a document with origin '{WEBCACHE URL}'
```

The obvious answer after looking at that is 'allow cross origin requests' but that's not really an option for me.

#### My Routes File (stripped down)

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './landing/landing.module#LandingModule' },
    { path: 'reviews/:slug', loadChildren: './article/article.module#ArticleModule' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];

export const AppContentRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue with my [website](https://city-sightseeing.com/). In search console we are gettina many inexplicables Soft 404 and I'm thinking that is could be for this error. Has you been able to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: No, haven't been able to resolve this so far. Just anxiously waiting on Universal Java support. Let me know if you get anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you having SEO problems too?
I opened an issue in Github for ask about this problem: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17157

Comment: Yeah I am having SEO problems. Luckily it's not critical right now but will be in future. Thanks for creating that issue, I'll keep my eye on it.

Comment: @IvanMoreno is there any way to debug.